# Spring-boot war application is running well on windows but not in ubuntu

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ubuntu-16.04, war

I have a spring-boot war application that runs perfectly in windows and ios, then I tried to run it in linux. It did run and build normally but when I tried to open it via browser it returns invalid http responses in chrome and some undeciphered codes in Firefox. I used this pc to run another spring-boot projects and they work just fine. I'm using Maven 3.3.9 and Ubuntu 16.04.

Here's what my pom.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>hris</artifactId>
<version>0.1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>hris</name>
<description>sso template for hris</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1212.jre7</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-layout-dialect -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.18</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- CAS Integration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.kakawait</groupId>
        <artifactId>cas-security-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
        <artifactId>datatables-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>22.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>checkstyle</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArgument>${compilerArgument}</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

And here's what's written out when I run the app

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building dapil 0.1
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ hris >>>
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ hris ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] Copying 1 resource
    [INFO] Copying 953 resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ hris ---
    [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ hris ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /******/src/test/resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ hris ---
    [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ hris <<<
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ hris ---

      .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.9.RELEASE)

    2018-04-12 12:49:22.096  INFO 30740 --- [           main] c.example.hris.HRISApplication  : Starting HRISApplication on Lenovo-G40-70 with PID 30740 (/*******/target/classes started by ****** in **********)
    2018-04-12 12:49:22.101  INFO 30740 --- [           main] c.example.hris.HRISApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
    2018-04-12 12:49:22.632  INFO 30740 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@9e79a00: startup date [Thu Apr 12 12:49:22 WIB 2018]; root of context hierarchy
    2018-04-12 12:49:24.064  WARN 30740 --- [           main] o.m.s.mapper.ClassPathMapperScanner      : No MyBatis mapper was found in '[com.example.hris]' package. Please check your configuration.
    2018-04-12 12:49:25.583  INFO 30740 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 12000 (https)
    2018-04-12 12:49:25.611  INFO 30740 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
    2018-04-12 12:49:25.613  INFO 30740 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
    2018-04-12 12:49:25.766  INFO 30740 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    2018-04-12 12:49:25.767  INFO 30740 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3141 ms
    2018-04-12 12:49:26.053  INFO 30740 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-04-12 12:49:26.054  INFO 30740 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-04-12 12:49:26.054  INFO 30740 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-04-12 12:49:26.055  INFO 30740 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-04-12 12:49:26.056  INFO 30740 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
    2018-04-12 12:49:26.057  INFO 30740 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
    2018-04-12 12:49:28.032  INFO 30740 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@9e79a00: startup date [Thu Apr 12 12:49:22 WIB 2018]; root of context hierarchy
    2018-04-12 12:49:28.050  INFO 30740 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Detected @ModelAttribute methods in siteController
    2018-04-12 12:49:28.175  INFO 30740 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/auth/edit/{id}],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.example.hris.controller.AuthController.postAuthEdit(com.example.hris.dto.form.cmd.AuthItemCmd,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)
    2018-04-12 12:49:28.176  INFO 30740 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/auth/create],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.example.hris.controller.AuthController.getAuthAdd(org.springframework.ui.Model)
    2018-04-12 12:49:28.177  INFO 30740 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/auth/create],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.example.hris.controller.AuthController.postAuthAdd(com.example.hris.dto.form.cmd.AuthItemChildCmd,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)
    2018-04-12 12:49:28.177  INFO 30740 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/auth/update/{id}],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.example.hris.controller.AuthController.getAuthEdit(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)
    2018-04-12 12:49:28.178  INFO 30740 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/auth/delete],methods=[POST]}" onto public boolean com.example.hris.controller.AuthController.postUserDeactivate(java.lang.String)
    2018-04-12 12:49:28.178  INFO 30740 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/auth/manage],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.example.hris.controller.AuthController.indexGet(com.example.hris.dto.form.search.AuthItemSearchForm,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.Model)
    2018-04-12 12:49:28.179  INFO 30740 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/auth/table],methods=[POST]}" onto public com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.ajax.DatatablesResponse<com.example.hris.dto.table.AuthItemItem> com.example.hris.controller.AuthController.postTableSearch(com.example.hris.dto.form.search.AuthItemSearchForm,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
    2018-04-12 12:49:28.181  INFO 30740 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/signin],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.example.hris.controller.SiteController.login()
    2018-04-12 12:49:28.181  INFO 30740 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.example.hris.controller.SiteController.index()
    2018-04-12 12:49:28.185  INFO 30740 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
    2018-04-12 12:49:28.186  INFO 30740 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
    2018-04-12 12:49:28.250  INFO 30740 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
    2018-04-12 12:49:28.251  INFO 30740 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
    2018-04-12 12:49:28.337  INFO 30740 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
    2018-04-12 12:49:29.686  INFO 30740 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/css/**'], Ant [pattern='/js/**'], Ant [pattern='/images/**'], Ant [pattern='/webjars/**'], Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico'], Ant [pattern='/error']]], []
    2018-04-12 12:49:29.830  INFO 30740 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/**']]], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@551f663f, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@223b66, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@37dc0139, org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter@4b658c91, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@274ccf4f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@13f8799a, org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter@764ed709, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@422b1740, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6e1eddc, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7886ebc0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@58ce6961, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@48408088, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4fa73638, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@46775723]
    2018-04-12 12:49:29.853  INFO 30740 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/**']]], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2ff438ee, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@d3ea90c, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@41ef1e45, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4e1c5a6a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@3657e01, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@381dbdc1, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1b991b1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4dd194c2, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@3b7b329e, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@7f495bf9, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@ad57ac4]
    2018-04-12 12:49:30.176  INFO 30740 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
    2018-04-12 12:49:31.983  INFO 30740 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 12000 (https)
    2018-04-12 12:49:31.991  INFO 30740 --- [           main] c.example.hris.HRISApplication  : Started HRISApplication in 10.454 seconds (JVM running for 16.918)
    2018-04-12 12:49:48.922  INFO 30740 --- [       Thread-4] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@9e79a00: startup date [Thu Apr 12 12:49:22 WIB 2018]; root of context hierarchy
    2018-04-12 12:49:48.928  INFO 30740 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried this on Ubuntu 17.10 but the same thing happened. Is there anything I can do to fix it? Thanks in advance

EDIT: I'm have openjdk8 in both version of ubuntu and windows. I'm not sure about the ios since its my friend's.

Here's how they look like when I tried to build it

[in chromium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3brh.png) & [in firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CXJp.png)

Comment: Could you please add some information on the precise error that happens when you try to open your app via browser?  We would need too to know the exact JVM versions that you are using in each environment.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I have openjdk 8 installed and i've put the error above. I notice when i tried to build the app it gives no myBatis mapper found. Is it possible that's the problem?

Comment: And no particular errors in the server log when the errors you show in the screen captures happen?

Comment: Are you sure port 12000 is available on that machine? I ask because https seems to be configured but I don't really see an indication in the browser screenshots that the browser is going to a secured url.

Comment: no, nothing happens in the logs

Comment: i tried to change the server. and cas port in application properties to the usual 9090 but it gave the same results

Comment: But what if you go to `https://localhost:portnumber` ?

Comment: it worked! Thanks! do you have any idea why is that?

Comment: Because you configured https, so you need to specify the https protocol in the url. Modern browsers are starting to assume https by default, but apparently that is not yet the case on that linux box.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem with spring-boot version 1.4.0.RELEASE and got resolved when switched to version 2.1.8.RELEASE